# Reading 3 of 9 extended bar codes using zxing - in Android

Tags: java, android, zxing, barcode-scanner

I am working on replacing an expensive set of bespoke bar code readers with a nice and simple android app.

I am calling the zxing package, and am able to read most bar codes, apart from Code 3 of 9 extended, which is the current standard barcode in our business (with over 2000 barcodes already in circulation).

Is there a way of extending the zxing package to include Code 3 of 9 Extended bar codes??

My current code, which opens the google goggles app and successfully displays QR code and most 1D barcodes information via a Toast call, and I have tried explicitly defining which codes to read but have commented that line out as without it, the scanner should read all possible codes (just for testing):

```
mGetScanButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonScan);
mGetScanButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
             Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
                //intent.putExtra("SCAN_FORMATS", "CODE_39,CODE_93,CODE_128,DATA_MATRIX,ITF,CODABAR,EAN_13,EAN_8,UPC_A,QR_CODE" );
                startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
        }

});

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    if (requestCode == 0) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            //  The Intents Fairy has delivered us some data!
            String contents = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
            //code below will be deleted after testing
            //String format = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT");
            // Toast call to display code when read
            Toast.makeText(this, contents, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            // Handle successful scan
        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // Handle cancel
        }
    }

}
```

Your assistance is much appreciated, I would prefer not to ask the staff to replace all the bar codes... although this may be required!

Example of Code 39 extended - encoded number = *25*

[image]

EDIT : My app is actually opening the Google Goggle app rather than the Barcode Scanner app from zxing!  I have now installed the correct Barcode Scanner app, and it works.  Many thanks all!

Comment: Would you provide a sample image of Barcode 3 of 9 extended ?

Comment: Code 3 of 9 is otherwise known as Code 39. ZXing already supports it and it should be enabled by default. Can you scan your barcode with the Barcode Scanner app?

Comment: Enrico, thank you, I did not have the correct app installed, and so the intent call was using Google Goggles, which doesn't seem to support Code 39 Extended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My app is actually opening the Google Goggle app rather than the Barcode Scanner app from zxing! I have now installed the correct Barcode Scanner app, and it works. Many thanks all!